# Find the missing strings containing int value from a given list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, sorting

Given a list of string, say `mystr= ["State0", "State1", "State2", "State5", "State8"]`.

I need to find the missing States (here `"State3", "State4", "State6", "State7"`). Is there a possibility to find it?

Desired output:  `mylist = ["State3", "State4", "State6", "State7"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough with list comprehensions and f-strings:

```
mystr = ["State0", "State1", "State2", "State5", "State8"]

highest = max(int(state.split('State')[-1]) for state in mystr)
mylist = [f"State{i}" for i in range(highest) if f"State{i}" not in mystr]

print(mylist)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['State3', 'State4', 'State6', 'State7']
> ```

Note that this solution is nice and general and will work even if the last element in the original list if for example "State1024", and even if the original list is not sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the highest number in the list might not be known, one way is to extract the numerical part in each string, take the `set.difference` with a `range` up to the highest value and create a new list using a list comprehension:

```
import re
ints = [int(re.search(r'\d+', i).group(0)) for i in mystr]
# [0, 1, 2, 5, 8]
missing = set(range(max(ints))) - set(ints)
# {3, 4, 6, 7}
[f'State{i}' for i in missing]
# ['State3', 'State4', 'State6', 'State7']
```

Comment: What does 'f' represent here, [f'State{i}' for i in missing]. throwing error at this line

Comment: This is python 3's string formatting syntax, you can read more about it [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), what python version do you have?

Comment: @Sharm it's an f-string, they are used for inserting variables inside strings: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Comment: @yatu, python 3.5

Comment: @Sharm try with `['State{}'.format(i) for i in missing]`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking. I think this is what you expect.

```
mystr= ["State0", "State1", "State2", "State5", "State8"]
print(['State'+str(p) for p in range(8) if 'State'+str(p) not in mystr ])
```

Comment: This is awfully specific and will not work if the last state in the original list is for example "State12".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
lst = ["State0", "State1", "State2", "State5", "State8"]

states = set(lst)    
len_states = len(states)
missing = []
num = 0

while len_states:
    state = f'State{num}'
    if state in states:
        len_states -= 1 
    else:
        missing.append(state)
    num += 1

print(missing)
```

Output:

`['State3', 'State4', 'State6', 'State7']`